# Incorrect rendering of Urdu content in dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am trying to make a pdf file from a blade view file using dompdf laravel package.
all the HTML elements are working fine but the urdu content is rendering separated each character. Like the actual urdu string is ڈاکٹر آصف علی but it is showing like this:

[image]

I have tried many fonts which supports urdu language text like DejaVu Sans ad Noto fonts and many other fonts I have tried but could not solve this issue. I have tried some other laravel packages one of them is rendering the urdu text in the correct way but that package don't support html and css styling.

Could anyone please let me know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Dom PDF does not support URDU but in Arabic,
There is only 1 way to fix this

> Download the ar-php library First form https://www.ar-php.org/ or somewhere you find better.

> Use this code to make your content will appear properly

```
require_once 'ar-php/src/Arabic.php';
$Arabic = new ArPHP\I18N\Arabic();

$html = "چونکہ اقوامِ متحدہ کی ممبر قوموں نے اپنے چارٹر میں بنیادی انسانی"



$p = $Arabic->arIdentify($html);

for ($i = count($p)-1; $i >= 0; $i-=2) {
    $utf8ar = $Arabic->utf8Glyphs(substr($html, $p[$i-1], $p[$i] - $p[$i-1]));
    $html   = substr_replace($html, $utf8ar, $p[$i-1], $p[$i] - $p[$i-1]);
}
```